# STRING database Neo4j import

Tags: database, import, neo4j

I have this network I'm working on from STRING database .
I have extracted that network so that I can impor it into Neo4j , 
The format I used is TSV and i have converted it to csv and done the import 
yet , I can see only nodes and no relationships in between .
How can I make Neo4j able to know the relationships .and represent them 
Here is the STRING network : http://string-db.org/cgi/network.pl?taskId=sPvqsEhi3Tk6&sessionId=MKQKZSH3dCb3&bottom_page_content=table

and that is the tabular form  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMMFk.png 
And here is the Neo4j graph [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKeYv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will do the trick :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT a.NodeID IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///strings.csv'
AS line
WITH line
MERGE (n1:Node {NodeID: line.node1_string_internal_id, NodeName: line.node1})
MERGE (n2:Node {NodeID: line.node2_string_internal_id, NodeName: line.node2})
MERGE (n1)-[:INTERACTS {Score: TOFLOAT(line.combined_score)}]->(n2);
```

I hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: I tried it now I'm getting Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 2 error, I'm sorry  I'm newbie in Cypher

Comment: Is not a problem. You first need to execute the CREATE statement in the browser and after that the rest of it.
The first statement (up to the first ";") creates an index (and constraint) for your nodes. The second statement does the actual loading based on the three things that can be found in each line in the CSV (two nodes and the relationship between them).